# Parachain stops producing blocks after runtime upgrade

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade

I am testing a parachain runtime upgrade locally. After calling the `enactAuthorizeUpgrade`, the parachain stops producing blocks, and the logs show error: `Collation wasn't advertised to any validator`.

I can see the parachain producing the same block repeatedly, but it seems like its never imported by the relay chain. Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I was performing the test using zombinet and a raw chain spec and the issue was due to the fact that the registered parachainId didn't match the parachainId specified in the raw chain spec. So the solution was to set the parachainId in the zombinet config to match the parachainId in the raw chain spec.